# Why is $B[x]/M$ algebraic over $B/m$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $B$ be a subring of some field $K$, $x$ some element in $K$, $m$ a maximal ideal in $B$ and $m[x]$ the extension of $m$ in $B[x]$ and $M$ a maximal ideal in $B[x]$ such that $m[x] \subset M $ and $M \cap B = m$.

Why is $B[x]/M$ algebraic over $B/m$? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $(B/\mathfrak m)$- algebra $B[x]/M$ is finitely generated (by $\bar x$) and is a field.
Hence by [Zariski's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172829/3217) it is finite-dimensional and *a fortiori* algebraic over $B/\mathfrak m$.

Comment: I'm now doubtful of my answer, because it doesn't seem like I proved anything nearly as strong. Was my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: Dear @Zev, I see a difficulty in your proof: it is not clear why the polynomial $f$ you obtain that kills $x+M$ is non-zero: for example its leading coefficient $a_n+\frak m$ would be  zero if  $a_n\in \mathfrak m$ . In other words: if (for example) $M=\mathfrak m[x]$ we are in trouble!

Comment: Ay, there's the rub. Thanks!