# Finitely Generated Algebra and Finite Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose $L,K$ are fields. Is is true that if $L$ a finitely generated $K$-algebra then $L/K$ is a finite field extension?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra) seems to think so. But if it is true surely it's difficult to prove? After all the Nullstellensatz would seem to follow immediately from such a result. Is this the basic idea of Noether Normalisation?

Any advice or guidance about a proof would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @EdwardHughes: This is one form of Nullstellensatz. It is not easier nor harder than Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at my answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172761/a-question-about-a-weak-form-of-hilberts-nullstellensatz/172789#172789). It proves using Noether Normalisation that the extension $L/K$ must necessarily be finite.

Comment: Aha - thank you. Didn't see that question. I guess mine is a slight duplicate of that one. As such it can probably just be closed!